# Express $\cos(\alpha/3)$ as a function of $\cos(\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

Ok simple question.
To give an expression for $\cos(\alpha/3)$ one can do the following trick:
$$\cos(3x)=\cos(2x+x)=\cos(2x)\cos(x)-\sin(2x)\sin(x)\\=[\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)]\cos(x)-2\sin^2(x)\cos(x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x).$$
By defining $\alpha=3x$, we have
$$4\cos^3(\alpha/3)-3\cos(\alpha/3)=\cos (\alpha).$$
However, I have not found any way to obtain an expression for $\cos(\alpha/3)$ solely as a function of $\cos(\alpha)$, as one can instead do with $\cos(\alpha/2)=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{1+\cos(\alpha)}$.

Is it simply impossible or is there a way to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed impossible.

There are closed-form formulas for the roots of a cubic equation. But in the case of three real roots, known as the *casus irreductibilis*, the solution requires… angle trisection (in fact, the cubic root of a complex), i.e. precisely the problem you are asking.

On another hand, expressing $\cosh\dfrac x3$ in terms of $\cosh x$ is doable:

$$\cosh x+\sqrt{\cosh^2x-1}=e^x,
\\e^{x/3}=\sqrt[3]{e^x},
\\\cosh\frac x3=\frac12\left(e^{x/3}+\frac1{e^{x/3}}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos0\ne\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}$, $\cos\frac{\alpha}{3}$ isn't a function of $\cos\alpha$.